How to get the input cursor x,y position without mouse-click?
I want to check the keyboard input cursor position [x, y] but I can only get the mouse cursor position, that means you have to mouse-click into the field position to get the cursor position. Is there a way to get the input cursor position after a tab navigation without this mouse click?

Detecting the position of the text input cursor (caret - I suppose that's what you're talking about) within an input field is more complex than detecting the mouse cursor position. This is because the text input cursor is managed by the operating system and some specific application. Care to give more insights as to what you've tried so far? Perhaps more context as well?

In a GUI you can go into the field with a mouse click or with the keyboard tab function. So if you want to scan the field value for test automation you need the actual input field position, this works only with a mouse click.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.! Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a Minimal Reproducible Example so we can better help you.
